# Is there a function in HiveMetaStoreClient which will give me all Partitions of a hive-table?

Tags: java, hive, hive-metastore

I have tried some functions like getPartition, getPartitionsByNames, listPartitions.
I need something like if i give the name of a partition column, then the function should return all the partitions of it existing in hdfs.

Example: Function(dbName, tableName, partitonColumnName)
Output: 12345, 12346, 12347, 12348
It should return all partitions existing in hdfs

Answer (score 0):

HiveMetastoreClient has `List<String> listPartitionNames(String dbName, String tblName, short max)`  method and `List<Partition>    listPartitions(String db_name, String tbl_name, short max_parts)` method.

See [listPartitions method](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html#listPartitions-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-short-).

Comment: I needed some function like if i give it a partition_column then it should return all the partition_values present in hdfs for that column, but the above methods has a Parameter short max_parts, which will give me Partition object for top max_parts rows.

Comment: @user15059143 but Hive metastore does not aware of what is in HDFS really exist. You can delete or add folders in HDFS in any moment and Hive metadata is not refreshed until repair table executed . So, you need to check HDFS separately

Comment: Got it , Thanks @leftjoin